# Kafka Streams Persistent Store cleanup

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is there some explicit cleanup needed to prevent each persistent store from growing too much in size? I am currently using it for calculating aggregations in DSL API.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Basically what would be the impact if size of a persistent state store is not kept in check because data is just added to it but never removed. And is there a recommended way to clean up such state stores. 

I can think of something like setting up a scheduler to delete old records(say something like older than 1 month) but was wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: You might be able to use a windowed store (depending on your needs). Or you can `schedule()` a `Punctuation` to delete old records manually.

Comment: On the impact of not keeping state store size checked: streams application will crash at some point. I tried this by creating a small partition on my filesystem (50mb), and made it the state directory. I make the processor save everything it reads off the topic to the state store, and it wasn't too long before the topology crashed with `no space left on device` errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We were having a similar issue, we simply scheduled a job for cleaning the store
in our processor/transformer.
Just implement your isDataOld(nextValue) and you are good to go.

```
@Override
public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
this.kvStore = (KeyValueStore<Key, Value>) this.context.getStateStore("KV_STORE_NAME");
this.context.schedule(60000, PunctuationType.STREAM_TIME, (timestamp) -> {
    KeyValueIterator<Key, Value> iterator = kvStore.all();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
    KeyValue<Key,Value> nextValue = iterator.next();
    if isDataOld(nextValue)
       kvStore.delete(nextValue.key);
    }

});
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of doing something similar. I am using only DSL now but seems like only Processor API has scheduling. Guess I can create a processor node just to clear out my state store.

Comment: You can combine the DSL API with the processor one with methods :`transform` or `process` in the DSL api.

Comment: Yup, having a processor node will cause no harm to your DSL code :)

Comment: Will there be any problem if you call delete while iterating through the state store?

Comment: NOTE : I asked on the Slack chat for KStreams and it seems deleting while iterating is okay for state store.

Comment: Glad to hear it ! :)
We should consider this closed

Comment: We can also try WALL_CLOCK_TIME instead of STREAM_TIME.

Comment: @SarfarazHussain of course you can but if nothing pass in the stream i don't want to waste resource executing such function. That's the reason of the STREAM_TIME

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
final var store =  Stores.persistentSessionStore(MATERIAL_STORE_NAME, Duration.ofDays(10));
    return Stores.sessionStoreBuilder(store,
            Serdes.Long(),
            keySpecificAvroSerde
    );
```